# How to call property from property in c# expression?

Tags: c#, expression

I have 3 classes.

```
    AutoYearMake{
       int Year { get; set; }
       string Make { get; set; }
            }

    AutoModel{
       IAutoYearMake AutoYearMakeParent { get; set; }
       string Model { get; set; }
            } 

    AutoTrim{
        IAutoModel AutoModelParent { get; set; }
        string Trim { get; set; }
            }
```

I need to create a query to a database. How can I get dynamically an expression like:

```
   Expression<Func<AutoTrim, bool>> expression =  expression = t => t.AutoModelParent.AutoYearMakeParent.Year == year.Value
                              && t.AutoModelParent.AutoYearMakeParent.Make 
                              == make && t.AutoModelParent.Model == model;
```

This is my code. It doesn't work.

```
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (AutoTrim), "a");

        MemberExpression yearProp = Expression.Property(parameter, "AutoModelParent.AutoYearMakeParent.Year");
        MemberExpression makeProp= Expression.Property(parameter, "AutoModelParent.AutoYearMakeParent.Make");
        MemberExpression modelProp= Expression.Property(parameter, "AutoModelParent.Model");

        Expression right = Expression.Constant(2014);
        Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(yearProp, right);
        right = Expression.Constant("make");
        Expression e2 = Expression.Equal(makeProp, right);
        right = Expression.Constant("model");
        Expression e3 = Expression.Equal(modelProp, right);

        Expression predicateBody = Expression.AndAlso(e1, e2);
        Expression final = Expression.AndAlso(e1, e2);
```

How can I resolve this problem? I tried to use Expression.Call. It wasn't right way.

Comment: Look at the expression `expression` and see how it is structured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of the `Expression.Property()` methods is object from which property should be accessed. If you want to access property `AutoModelParent` from parameter `t` you use:

```
Expression.Property(parameter, "AutoModelParent")
```

So, if you want to access Model property of AutoModelParent property of parameter t you can go with:

```
Expression.Property(Expression.Property(parameter, "AutoModelParent"), "Model")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this solution:

```
private static MemberExpression GetPropertyPathAccessor(Expression parameter, string path)
{
    return (MemberExpression) path.Split('.').Aggregate(parameter, Expression.Property);
}
```

or if you don't like one-liners

```
private static MemberExpression GetPropertyPathAccessor(Expression parameter, string path)
{
    Expression current = parameter;
    foreach (var propertyName in path.Split('.'))
    {
        current = Expression.Property(current, propertyName);
    }
    return (MemberExpression)current;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
MemberExpression yearProp = GetPropertyPathAccessor(parameter, "AutoModelParent.AutoYearMakeParent.Year");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

After that you have the Func<> in expFunc and you can use it right away.

```
var argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(AutoTrim), "s");
var expFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<AutoTrim, bool>>(
        Expression.AndAlso(
            Expression.AndAlso(
                Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Property(Expression.Property(Expression.Property(argParam, "AutoModelParent"), "AutoYearMakeParent"), "Year"), 
                    Expression.Constant(year.Value)),
                Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Property(Expression.Property(Expression.Property(argParam, "AutoModelParent"), "AutoYearMakeParent"), "Make"),
                    Expression.Constant(make))
            ),
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(Expression.Property(argParam, "AutoModelParent"), "Model"), 
                Expression.Constant(model))
        ),
        argParam
    ).Compile();
```

But of course you need these too (just example values):

```
int? year = 2000;
string make = "BMW";
string model = "6";
```